# Scroll the div over which another div is overlayed

Tags: html, css

I have a container div with two div's inside.

```css
.class {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: #82CAFF;
}

.map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="map"></div>
</div>
```

With this setup, I have a map and a circle on top of it. I want to make the map still scrollable even with the circle overlay. Any suggestion on this? Thank you.

Comment: `pointer-events: none;` on the circle ?

Comment: position: fixed on the circle?

Comment: I tried both, but still, the div underneath isn't scrollable.  Thank you for your response